# MS Access open error message

Tags: ms-access

When I tried to open MS Access from the command line I got the following error message:

> The command line you used to start Microsoft Office Access contains an option that micosoft Access doesn't recognize.

My command is very simple:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" E:\MonthlyCompAudit\"Audit - Test - Copy.accdb"
```

If I just run

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
```

it works.

After I included the database name, it does not work. The Access file path/name is current, because I verified with `dir` command.

Answer (score 4):

Your quotation marks are around only the file name, not the entire path. Try:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "E:\MonthlyCompAudit\Audit - Test - Copy.accdb"
```

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6

> You can include a path, if necessary. If the path contains spaces, enclose it in quotation marks.

Comment: Good call - I moved the quote position and it works. I do have a few extra questions: (1) Is there a way this batch runs on 'silence' mode that does not disturb other users? (2) In my command line, I plan to call a Macro with -x option. The Macro is a function that pop up a message box and asked for 'Yes' or 'No'  - how can I let the batch know that a defaut 'Yes' is always selected?

Comment: @PaulZ Those questions are probably better answered by raising two new questions.

Comment: @PaulZ If the link I provided does not answer your additional questions regarding further switches, please raise new questions.